# want to understand concept of multiple recursion

Tags: c#, c

for example let me take the example of merge sort

```js
mergesort(int a[], int low, int high)
{
  int mid;
  if(low<high)
  {
   mid=(low+high)/2;
   mergesort(a,low,mid);
   mergesort(a,mid+1,high);
   merge(a,low,high,mid);
  }
}
```

here in which order recursion statement gets executed
i have read some logic relating tree structure but i am having hard time understanding it..
please help i have been stuck on it  for ages

Comment: Trace it step by step on a paper and using a debugger if necessary.

Comment: welcome to SO. There are so many resources about recursion out there, what did you try?

Comment: i am  starting to get a grip of it by tree method,earlier i tried to do it simply by logic

Answer (score 4):

It is basically a pre-order traversal of a binary tree.

There is only one thread so everything get executed sequentially. So the first time the initial `mergesort` function calls itself the same thing happens over and over until the base case is reached. That is why base cases are so important when using recursion; otherwise you get infinite recursion, and... stack overflow!

Looking at the problem from the very top level, the lower half of the array gets completely sorted, then the higher half gets completely sorted, and then those two sorted arrays are merged together to give you the entire array sorted.

From the next level down the lower half has its own lower half sorted, and then its higher half sorted. This continues until `low < high` is false. In that case the function just returns. And then the second `mergesort` gets called in the `mergesort` that called it.

If you draw it out on paper you will see that the tree grows down the side that represents the sorting of the lower half back up to the root and then down the opposite side until it hits the base case and goes back up to root.

[image]

Comment: yeah,but can you please explain this with example of trees by taking n(example 4 or 8) element merge sort

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that `a` has 4 elements.
`(low, high)` represents `mergesort(a, low, high)`. And the number in `[]` represents the order that the function returns.

```
                     [10](0                ,                  3)
                                         /  \                           
                      [4](0    ,        1)   [8](2    ,       3)
                              / \                    / \        
                      [1](0, 0)  [2](1, 1)   [5](2, 2) [6](3, 3)
                            \         /            \        /
                            [3]merge               [7]merge
                                \                      /
                                       [9]merge
```

Answer (score 1):

First in last out.

The first function call will pause when the sub call is triggered, it will wait for the return value to continue.

So I'll comment your example with the return order

```
mergesort(int a[], int low, int high) //fourth
{
  int mid;
  if(low<high)
  {
   mid=(low+high)/2;
   mergesort(a,low,mid); // This should be executed and returned first. it will create a chain of functions, it need to be resolved in reverse order before the program continues.
   mergesort(a,mid+1,high); // second
   merge(a,low,high,mid); //third
  }
}
```

However each of the sub functions will spawn their own mergsort functions which will have its own iterations.

That is said, the main mergesort will spawn alot of sub mergsort functions like a chain, once the chain spawning is completed, the last ring of the chain should be able to resolve, that is is should not satisfy (low

If you have experience in BASIC, I would recommend you try it there, they usually allow line by line execution and you can "see" how the code is executed.

Comment: It can also be noted that you don't need a low-high pairing. This is C, and as such your parameter `a[]` is nothing but a pointer anyway. The sublists invokes use pointer arithmetic for the split. I.e this can simply be `mergesort(int a[], size_t len)`. The mid point is simply `size_t mid = len/2`, and the sublist invokes are `mergesort(a,mid)` and `mergesort(a+mid, len-mid)`. To use the OP's existing `merge()` function you then call `merge(a,0,len,mid);` but I would likely redo that as well to simply be `merge(int a[], size_t len, size_t mid)` since the zero can be assumed.